# Throws Error "out_of_range" for "find_first_of"

Tags: c++, string

I have no idea why the first codeblock is working and the second is not:
For both blocks there is:

```
struct Object
{
    vector <string> line;
};

Object myObject;
string a = "*Nset, nset=_PickedSet2, internal, generate";
myObject.line.push_back(a);
int iPos = 0; 
int iPos2 = 7;  
string sRefString = ",";     // So I want to find the ",".
iPos = myObject.line.at(0).find_first_of(sRefString, iPos2);    //Here is the issue.
```

So this works just fine:

```
cout <<"Output: "<< myObject.line.at(0).find_first_of(sRefString, iPos2);
```

It gives:

```
Output: 23
```

But this does not:

```
iPos = myObject.line.at(0).find_first_of(sRefString, iPos2);
```

Here i get an error:

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
zweiterminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what():  basic_string::substr
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: The above code (a) won't compile (`line` vs. `list`) and (b) would throw an out-of-range error at the `myObject.line.at(0) = "*...` assignment. Can you include some actual, working code that shows the issue?

Comment: Oh Sorry! I had two versions for my question and mixed them up. I hope it's fine now. Thanks Paul.

Comment: Still doesn't show the error: https://ideone.com/fYFvyS

Comment: Hmm. Makes the problem just more mysterious... Thanks anyway.

Comment: Without a tag for the language being used, this question doesn't have much value for future users of this site. Can you edit to add one, please? (It will help you get an answer more quickly, too, as people who watch that tag will see the question.)

Comment: The problem was solved by renaming "iPos", and then name it back. :D
I changed the tag.
Thanks for your time, guys!